# NBuilder - How to create a collection that contains several derived class

Tags: c#, mocking, nbuilder

I have entities:

```
BaseEntity (Base Class & Abstract)
DerivedOne (based on BaseEntity)
DerivedTwo (based on BaseEntity)
...
```

Is it possible to build a list (collection) of `BaseEntity` but contains instance of the derived classes only?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I mean is it possible to create the list using NBuilder `Build<BaseEntity>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible here is the sample

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<BaseEntity> list = new List<BaseEntity>();
        DerivedOne d1 = new DerivedOne() { bp1 = 1, Name = "DerivedOne" };
        DerivedTwo d2 = new DerivedTwo() { bp1 = 2, Name = "DerivedTwo" }; 

        list.Add(d1);
        list.Add(d2);

    }
}

public class BaseEntity
{
    public int bp1 { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedOne : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedTwo : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention NBuilder on the content. please see my edit.